# tar --exclude '*/logs' doesn't work

Tags: tar

I try to exclude every folder called 'logs' in my tar prompt (I don't need to backup all my log files)

Simplified my prompt looks like this:

```
tar -cvpf backup.tar servers --exclude='*/logs'
```

and my file-system like this:

```
/home/
    backup.sh
    servers/
        server1/
            logs/
                logfile1
                logfile2
        server2/
            logs/
                logfile1
                logfile2
        [server3 ... server100]/
```

If I run the script it does not exclude the log-folders whereas if I run the following it does:

```
tar -cvpf backup.tar servers --exclude=server1/logs --exclude=server2/logs (and so on for the rest of the servers)
```

So how can I change my command so that I don't have to copy-paste the exclude command for every server and most likely produce some mistakes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU tar (v. 1.29), it works for me with `tar cvf foo.tar --exclude "*/logs" servers`.

It seems that the `--exclude` option only applies to paths listed after it on the command line, so this would not exclude `a/logs`:

```
tar cvf foo.tar servers/a --exclude "*/logs" servers/{b,c}
```

I can't see that mentioned explicitly in the man page though (but the synopsis lists options before files, as usual).