# Tar: Exclude folders that have a dynamic name (using wildcard)

Tags: tar

I have a backup routine that runs for Wordpress sites. There are folders created which are dynamic per installation of Wordpress. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to exclude the dynamic folder.

The convention for the dynamic folders are as follows:

```
/var/www/client1/public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-aaa1b23456-backups
/var/www/client2/public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-ccc7d89012-backups
```

The dynamic portions are `backupwordpress-aaa1b23456-backups` and `backupwordpress-ccc7d89012-backups`.

I have tired all of the following combinations, and none of them exclude the `backupwordpress-*-backups` folder.

```
tar zcpf client1.tgz /var/www/client1 --exclude="./public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*"
tar zcpf client1.tgz /var/www/client1 --exclude="./public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*/"
tar zcpf client1.tgz /var/www/client1 --exclude="./public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*-backups"
tar zcpf client1.tgz /var/www/client1 --exclude="./public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*-backups/"
tar zcpf client1.tgz /var/www/client1 --exclude="./public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*/*"
tar zcpf client1.tgz /var/www/client1 --exclude="./public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*-backups/*"
tar zcpf client1.tgz /var/www/client1 --exclude="/var/www/client1/public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*"
tar zcpf client1.tgz /var/www/client1 --exclude="/var/www/client1/public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*/*"
tar zcpf client1.tgz /var/www/client1 --exclude="/var/www/client1/public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*-backups"
tar zcpf client1.tgz /var/www/client1 --exclude="/var/www/client1/public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*-backups/*"
tar zcpf client1.tgz --exclude="./public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*" /var/www/client1
tar zcpf client1.tgz --exclude="./public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*/" /var/www/client1
tar zcpf client1.tgz --exclude="./public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*-backups" /var/www/client1
tar zcpf client1.tgz --exclude="./public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*-backups/" /var/www/client1
tar zcpf client1.tgz --exclude="./public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*/*" /var/www/client1
tar zcpf client1.tgz --exclude="./public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*-backups/*" /var/www/client1
tar zcpf client1.tgz --exclude="/var/www/client1/public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*" /var/www/client1
tar zcpf client1.tgz --exclude="/var/www/client1/public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*/*" /var/www/client1
tar zcpf client1.tgz --exclude="/var/www/client1/public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*-backups" /var/www/client1
tar zcpf client1.tgz --exclude="/var/www/client1/public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*-backups/*" /var/www/client1
```

Here is my version:

```
tar (GNU tar) 1.29
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe just `--exclude="backupwordpress-*-backups"`? If those are the only directories with that sort of name, that ought to match. This would be easier than trying to get the path right.  Also, I would put `--exclude` before the pathname of the directory you're archiving (although since you're using GNU `tar`, I suppose it doesn't matter since GNU utilities tend to reorder the command line arguments, for convenience).

Comment: The exclusion works for me (on an older `tar` version) when I use either `--exclude='*/backupwordpress-*-backups'` or a relative path `--exclude='var/www/client1/public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*-backups'`; I wonder if, when tar strips the leading `/`, it stops matching your fully-qualified exclusion pattern?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/450154/117549: "It seems that the --exclude option only applies to paths listed after it on the command line"

Comment: @JeffSchaller Both of these variations work. I must have made a typo or failed to test since this example was covered in my description. The position of the exclude was important.

```tar zcpf client1.tgz --exclude="/var/www/client1/public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*-backups" /var/www/client1``` or 
```tar zcpf client1.tgz --exclude="var/www/client1/public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*-backups" /var/www/client1```

Comment: @Kusalananda You were right about the position of the ```--exclude```. See my comment immediately above.

Comment: My comment about the slashes was more about tar stripping *leading* slashes when you request an archive of a full path name (one starting with `/`).  In any event, do you still have a problem to solve?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Understood. The problem has been solved, thank you!

Comment: @BrianJM do you have any interest in post a self-answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I must have made a typo or failed to test completely, since [the example/note that @JeffSchaller provided](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552979/tar-exclude-folders-that-have-a-dynamic-name-using-wildcard?noredirect=1#comment1026742_552979) was covered in my description. The position of the exclude is important.

These two variations work for me in `tar (GNU tar) 1.29`.

```
tar zcpf client1.tgz --exclude="/var/www/client1/public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*-backups" /var/www/client1
tar zcpf client1.tgz --exclude="var/www/client1/public_html/wp-content/backupwordpress-*-backups" /var/www/client1
```